# Ajax auto update when db updated

Tags: mysql, ajax

I need my text to auto update when the mySQL database is updated.
Could someone please help with this? I've looked a lot and no post says what I need, i'm new to ajax and don't know much about it. All I know is HTML, CSS, PHP and javascript.

Comment: Can you post your html at least? It'll make it easier for us to explain

Comment: I am actually just testing this for now and have no HTML. all i need is text. Like <font></font>. The site is http://www.twistmania.net/

Comment: Ok, I hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you might wanna check [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It'll be very simple if you know javascript, and it'll make your development a lot easier.

Then you need to check how an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is implemented with jQuery. Again, really simple, here's an example.

**test.php**

```
$var1 = $_POST['key'];
$var2 = $_POST['key1'];

//Some code here

echo 'Test finished'; // This is returned to the ajax call
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
         url:   '/test.php', 
        type:   'POST', /*Method, POST or GET depending on your needs*/
       async:  true, /*This makes the ajax call asyncronously or not*/
        data: {'key':value,'key2':value2},/*data to send*/
     success: function(result){  /*Return from PHP side*/

            /* result contains the data replied from the PHP script. */
            alert(result);

        }
});
```

If you want to replace some parts of your HTML you might wanna check functions like, [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/),etc. Also learn something about [JSON](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it's a data format. Really simple and yet magnificent

Hope this helps you! It looks like homework, but you'll ace it in no time, you'll see.